# Does Go allow specification of an interface for a map with particular key type?

Tags: interface, go

I wrote a function that would return a sorted slice of strings from a map[string]Foo.  I'm curious what is the best way to create a generic routine that can return a sorted slice of strings from any type that is a map with strings as keys.

Is there a way to do it using an interface specification?  For example, is there any way to do something like:

```
type MapWithStringKey interface {
    <some code here>
}
```

To implement the interface above, a type would need strings as keys.  I could then write a generic function that returns a sorted list of keys for fulfilling types.

This is my current best solution using the reflect module:

```
func SortedKeys(mapWithStringKey interface{}) []string {
    keys := []string{}
    typ := reflect.TypeOf(mapWithStringKey)
    if typ.Kind() == reflect.Map && typ.Key().Kind() == reflect.String {
        switch typ.Elem().Kind() {
        case reflect.Int:
            for key, _ := range mapWithStringKey.(map[string]int) {
                keys = append(keys, key)
            }
        case reflect.String:
            for key, _ := range mapWithStringKey.(map[string]string) {
                keys = append(keys, key)
            }
            // ... add more cases as needed
        default:
            log.Fatalf("Error: SortedKeys() does not handle %s\n", typ)
        }
        sort.Strings(keys)
    } else {
        log.Fatalln("Error: parameter to SortedKeys() not map[string]...")
    }
    return keys
}
```

[Click for Go Playground version](http://play.golang.org/p/ROsq9u40PP)

I'm forced to code type assertions for each supported type even though at compile time, we should know the exact type of the mapWithStringKey parameter.

Comment: I'm afraid you'd need generics. Generics, famously enough, are not included in the Go language. This being said there aren't so many cases where the use of generics would really simplify a problem : they generally add more layers and complexity.

Comment: I was afraid of that... oh well.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot make partial types. But you can define an interface which serves your purpose:

```
type SortableKeysValue interface {
    // a function that returns the strings to be sorted
    Keys() []string
}

func SortedKeys(s SortableKeysValue) []string {
    keys := s.Keys()
    sort.Strings(keys)
    return keys
}

type MyMap map[string]string

func (s MyMap) Keys() []string {
    keys := make([]string, 0, len(s))
    for k, _ := range s {
        keys = append(keys, k)
    }
    return keys
}
```

Try it here: http://play.golang.org/p/vKfri-h4Cp

Comment: Your solution doesn't address the real issue: for every different type that has strings as keys, you have to write another Keys() func.  Using reflect leads to a simpler solution that also requires modification for each type: [see reflect-based single func solution here](http://play.golang.org/p/ROsq9u40PP)

Comment: I take my above comment back.  I think your solution is better than the reflect-based one even if it's a bit more verbose.  Requiring a Keys() method will allow compile-time checking and the added methods can be next to the type's code.

Comment: exactly. also the compiler is optimise (inline) this code which it cannot do for the one-function solution. And this also scales well when a map-of-strings is a bit to naive as a data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Hope that helps (go-1.1):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
"reflect"
)

var m = map[string]int{"a": 3, "b": 4}

func MapKeys(m interface{}) (keys []string) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(m)
    for _, k := range v.MapKeys() {
        keys = append(keys, k.Interface().(string))
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", MapKeys(m))
}
```