# golang: traverse arbitrary map in sorted key order

Tags: dictionary, go

**In short: How do I traverse a map in sorted key order, regardless of the map's type?**

I found a few related questions, [the closest one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13291958/744071) suggesting that it can't be done without relying on the `reflect` module. Is this understanding correct?

Consider this Go code, which traverses two maps of different types, in sorted order of their keys:

```
mapOne := map[int]string {
    1: "a",
    2: "b",
    3: "c",
}
keysOne := make([]int, 0, len(mapOne))
for key, _ := range mapOne {
    keysOne = append(keysOne, key)
}
sort.Ints(keysOne)
for _, key := range keysOne {
    value := mapOne[key]
    fmt.Println(key, value)
}

mapTwo := map[string]int {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
}
keysTwo := make([]string, 0, len(mapTwo))
for key, _ := range mapTwo {
    keysTwo = append(keysTwo, key)
}
sort.Strings(keysTwo)
for _, key := range keysTwo {
    value := mapTwo[key]
    fmt.Println(key, value)
}
```

The logic to extract the keys and then sort them is duplicated for the two
different map types. **Is there any way to factor out this logic and avoid
duplication?**

I got stuck trying to write an interface to provide a `SortedKeys` method. In
particular, the return type of `SortedKeys` depends on the type of the map,
and I can't figure out how to express that in Go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think whoever told you you'd need `reflect` was correct; that's probably overkill though. I think the duplication is acceptable here.

(alternatively, you could implement your own map that uses some kind of interface for keys, but you'd still end up needing to make a type that satisfies the interface for each underlying key type)

Comment: Yeah, this is the sort of duplication that will drive you nuts at first when programming in Go but after a little while you figure out to make your data structures so you don't do it too often and when you do it just makes each bit of code that much simpler so it balances out in the end.

Comment: IMHO the whole idea of "traverse map in sorted key order" is flawed: Maps in Go just do not have this property. Actually Hash Maps in general don't have this property. If your algorithm requires this type of traversal you should use a different data structure: The mentioned "your own map" (which might be better describes as a balanced tree than a map).